# why is 1[1] evaluated to undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is the number 1 cast to an empty array implicitly?

```
> a = 1[1]
undefined
> console.log(a)
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: `1` is a `Number`

Comment: because a Number has no property `1`. this is cast to `Object(1)[1]` wich is the same as `(new Number(1))[1]`

Comment: Pretty much the same as [Why is `0[0]` syntactically valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250950/why-is-00-syntactically-valid/29251025#29251025)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the number 1 cast to an empty array implicitly?

No. The number value is implicitly (and temporarily) converted to a number *object* and the property `1` is accessed on that object.

The *bracket notation* you are using (`[1]`) is not specific to arrays, *every* object property can be accessed via bracket notation. I.e. the following two are equivalent: `obj.foo` (dot notation) and `obj['foo']` (bracket notation).

Number objects however don't have a property `1` and accessing a non-existing property returns `undefined`:

```js
var numObj = new Number(1);
console.log(numObj[1]);
```

---

The implicit conversion happens every time you access a *property* on a *primitive value*, whether the property exists or not. In the following example, the primitive number value is also implicitly converted to an object and then its `toFixed` method is executed:

```js
var num = 42;
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
// or equivalently to your example:
console.log(42['toFixed'](2))
```

Numbers, Strings, Booleans and Symbols have object equivalents. Null and Undefined don't.