# Why 1["foo"] returns undefined instead of an error?

Tags: javascript

Today I came accross a strange thing in Javascript.
When in Chrome console if I execute :

```
> 1["foo"]
```

Chrome console returns :

```
undefined
```

I was expecting an error though. How is it possible? I fall on that by studying the underscore.js (an old version) `invoke` method that seems to use that JavaScript property:

```
 // Invoke a method (with arguments) on every item in a collection.
  _.invoke = function(obj, method) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    var isFunc = _.isFunction(method);
    return _.map(obj, function(value) {
      var func = isFunc ? method : value[method];
      return func == null ? func : func.apply(value, args);
    });
  };
```

As you can see, `value` could be a number and if `1["foo"]` was raising an error, that code would be unsafe as I could do the following by mistake:

```
var a = {'foo' : 1}
_.invoke(a, 'foo'}
```

Comment: "Today I came accross a strange thing in Javascript".. This happens to me everyday

Comment: haha but it was stranger  than usual :D

Comment: You're using "bracket notation" to attempt to access the `foo` property on the `1` object.

Comment: `1.foo.foo` would be an error.

Comment: For the same reason `1['toString']` will return `ƒ toString() { [native code] }`. All js types are objects that have properties and methods.

Comment: Have you ever used `(1).toString()` or similar? It's more common in variables, e.g. `let x = 1, y = x.toString();`. Same thing, really.

Comment: Closer to [Why is 0\[0\] syntactically valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29250950) perhaps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything, even primitives, are essentially objects and *can* have members (properties, methods, etc). All the code in question is doing is attempting to find a member on `1` with the name `foo` which is not found so `undefined` is returned.